# How to solve error with calling kotlin activity method from java singleton?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I would like to call this method:

```
fun workingWithBtn(k: Int) {
        when (k) {
            1 -> {
                btn_submit_t.showError();
                Handler().postDelayed({
                    this@LoginScr.runOnUiThread {
                        btn_submit_t.hideLoading()
                        btn_submit_t.isEnabled
                    }
                }, 1000)
            }
            2 -> {
                btn_submit_t.showSuccess()
            }
            3 -> Handler().postDelayed({
                clickCount--
                this@LoginScr.runOnUiThread {
                    btn_submit_t.hideLoading()
                    btn_submit_t.isEnabled
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
```

this method is placed at the kotlin-based activity and I would like to call it from java singleton. I call this method from singleton like this:

```
new LoginScr().workingWithBtn(3);
```

but I receive the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
```

as I understand my class can't find my button. I tried to use findViewById and then work with btn but it didn't help me. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: it does not matter whether it is `kotlin` or `java` - you should never try to create an instance of Activity manually. Only system should create them. You have to find another way to call something in activity.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, I have made this via Java and right now I try to make it via kotlin, so I think that they have small differences

Comment: they for sure have, but any way `you should never try to create an instance of Activity manually.`

Comment: so, maybe you have some advice for me how to make what I want? because I would like to call activity method from singleton

Comment: you can use a static instance of your activity (a bad way), or a LocalBroadcast, or one of the Event libraries (EventBus for example)

Comment: and as I understand I can use for example LocalBroadcast for method calling?

Comment: not exactly. You can use it to send broadcasts to your activity. And in the activity you can receive them, and depending on the data sent in broabcast, you can call the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem via BroadcastReceiver. For this solution we have to add to our singleton to the place where we will need a function call these lines:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("btn_task"); // name of your filter
intent.putExtra("url", 1);
context.sendBroadcast(intent); // here you won't need context but I have to use it from singleton
```

then we create a variable at the activity:

```
lateinit var receiver: BroadcastReceiver
```

then we will assign the value:

```
val filter = IntentFilter("btn_task") // we will filter all intents with our filter
```

and then we have to create and register our receiver:

```
receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                workingWithBtn(intent.extras.getInt("url"))
            }
        }
registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
```

delete receiver when activity will be destroyed:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(receiver)
    }
```

maybe it will help someone else. Good Luck :)